# SQL Statement fails to insert values into database, but only appends an ID?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

** **EDIT: I resolved the issue on my own. Thanks for all your help.** **

I'm trying to insert image files to my database for testing, and found that my code stopped working (it was able to do what it did before).

When I submit the image to the database it appends the image id, but not the 'username' and 'img_name'(filename) fields - these two fields just show up as empty strings. Can you tell me what's wrong with my code and how I can fix this? Your help is very appreciated

This is a summary of my database:

```
Database Name: photos
Table Name: images
Row Names: id[primary key], username, img_name
```

And my HTML and PHP codes for uploading image file to the database:

```
<form method="post" action="uploadindex5.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="membimg">
    <input type="submit" name="membupload">
</form>
```

```html
if (isset($_POST['membupload'])) {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $membupload = $_POST['membupload'];
    $membimg = $_POST['membimg']['name'];
    $membtarg = "images/".basename($_FILES['membimg']['name']);
    $membmuf = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['membimg']['tmp_name'], $membtarg);
    
    $servername = "localhost";
    $sroot = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "photos";
    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername,$sroot,$password,$dbname);
    
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        throw new Exception(mysqli_connect_error(), mysqli_connect_errno());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (username, img_name) VALUES ('$username', '$membimg')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($membmuf) {
            $msg = "Image uploaded";
        } else {
            $msg = "Upload failed";
        }
}
```

Comment: `sql-server` is a DB seperate from `mysql`. `$_POST['membimg']['name']` I'd guess doesnt exist. Use error reporting, also you are open to SQL injections. Parameterize.

Comment: If your code stopped working, do a side-by-side diff comparison between the working code and non-working code.

Comment: @SamM that's what I did, but some reason the old code cannot add any values to the database anymore. I'm not sure what happened. This new code is able to add a value, but only an id.

Comment: @codo7081 Your question said the old code stopped working. But it stopped working without any code changes? Something has to have changed....either the code, the database, the PHP version, file structure on your server, or html form.

Comment: @SamM Yeah I added and changed text on the file where the old code existed. I'm sure that's what's causing the error, I just thought there was just an error I made on the code that somebody could point out.

Comment: But I guess it's more complicated than that.

Comment: Instead of editing the question with `I resolved the issue on my own. Thanks for all your help.` post your solution as an answer, if it was a coding issue. If not a coding issue the question can be deleted.

Comment: @chris85 Yeah that's what I initially meant to do - delete the question since it couldn't be resolved. But last time I did that an editor replied that "it was not common courtesy".

Answer (score 0):

I'd put dummy values in for the session and post values just hard code it and see if the PHP code is working and then determine if those variables are even set once i verified my php code works properly. Once you hard code those questionable variables then you can run the PHP page without submiting it with the form or ajax or however you are calling it. The PHP page will report the errors if you have PHP error reporting on. Javascript console may even tell you if there is a 500 internal server error which indicates the PHP script isn't working.

Comment: I think I'll try your suggestion and see if I get any results. I didn't think about dummy values/hard coding before